# ArcGIS Server 10.1 login error

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, installation

Trying to login into my AGS server 10.1 via server manager throws an error 
see atatched pic

[image]

Comment: No answer there yet, but also posted on [ArcGIS forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/94190-Unable-to-Login-into-ArcGIS-Server-10.1-manager-Dojo-invalid-key-given-error)

Answer (score 2):

Server Manager, or ArcMap too for that matter, handles the issuance and transfer of tokens automatically the first time you authenticate by username and password. The token contains a key, which is used to validate access. The tokens are by default tied to an IP address to which they were issued. If your IP changed, you'll have an issue. These tokens can also expire and throw the same error.

To request a new token navigate to `http://yourserver:6080/arcgis/tokens` in a web browser and authenticate through there. It is also possible to request a shared key which is not tied to a specific IP address. I have no idea what your specific issue is, but I hope some of this helps.